# How to print a horizontal line that is as long as the user inputs it

Tags: python, string

If I want to create a horizontal line of asterisks that is decided by the user, how would I do that? For example, I want to print a line that shows
01:...........(custom number)
02:........(custom number)
03:.......(custom number)
etc...
In this case I am taking the sales number from a file and printing a number of asterisks that represent the companies earnings in hundreds on any given day. In case that changes anything.

Sorry, edit: This is in python

Comment: What programming language? What have you tried?

Comment: then tag it as python, please

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
print '*' * n
```

where `n` is the number of asterisks you wish to display.

Here is a more complete example:

```
lens = [3, 5, 10, 1]
for i, l in enumerate(lens):
  print '%02d:%s' % (i + 1, '*' * l)
```

This displays:

```
01:***
02:*****
03:**********
04:*
```

Comment: FWIW, in 2020 I had to put parenthesis: `print('*'*n)`

Comment: That's because the example is in Python 2.

Answer (score 9):

The following answer only applies if you want to plot a horizontal line in Jupyter Lab / Jupyter Notebook:

```py
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
display(Markdown('---'))
```

Looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to multiply it by the length of the input? if so you can do the following:

```
x=raw_input("number/message: ")
y="*"*len(x)
print y
```

However, if you are looking to get x amount of "*" to a number you can do:

```
x=int(raw_input("number: "))
y="*"*x
print y
```